# asp.net event related problem

Tags: asp.net

hello friends i have a check box list which contains all the courses kept in the data base(on page load) now i want that on some event of check box list all branches corresponding to each checked box of course check box list should be list in another check box list(that is the business logic i will do my own) but the problem is that i am not finding any event where i can send all selected check box list value and can generate appropriate result, if any alternate control or solution you can suggest then please suggest me this.

Comment: You need to post some code to understand whats happens.

Comment: The select all, is a javascript part.

Comment: i just want to perform action for those which are selected check box from list so that it can generate all required branches corresponding to all selected check box so i just want to know some event for this where i can do this because if i use selected index change then on very first check box check it will happen post back while i want event or some alternate solution where it can wait until all needed check box are checked from check boxlist

Comment: do i need to give a separate button where i can see for all checked list box and can generate appropriate result.. but i don't want to give any button is there some alternate solutions or control vailable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the AutoPostBack property to true and in the SelectedIndexChanged event you can loop over the elements that are selected and then bind your second control depending on that.

Another option would be to go for an ajax solution. For this I suggest you take a look at the [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) in jQuery to bind to your checkboxlist and use the [ajax stack](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) to retrieve the extra information as html and plug that into a span as innerHtml.

Comment: you got me right...but still a bit wary.
would not it post back soon after i check the very first check box will it wait until i click all require check box ?

Comment: it simply post back on very first check box click ..don't wait for other to select

Comment: well i am using a separate button now but i dint want to use this it could be nice if it were done automatically after selecting all required check box ..well thanks for answer, was of great help

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clarify where your logic sits, and where the information required for that logic to work sits - in order to even know whether you're dealing with a client-side or a server-side technology question
There's two basic possibilities:

Either all required inforamtion is already in the loaded page. In that case, this is basically a javascript problem. I'd dive a bit into jQuery here which has excellent capabilities of finding elements based on properties, and manipulating them

Alternatively, some of your logic and/or data remains on the server. In that case, you can

1. go with the AutoPostBack property XIII mentioned, resulting, as you correctly assume, in a reload after every click.
2. Have the user click all the checkboxes they like, and then have them click on a "do something now" button which performs a single postback
3. Transmit the information about the checkbox click to the server via javascript, get a response, and select other boxes accordingly. Again, XIII already mentioned that by "ajax solution".

So I'm just trying to elaborate on what different approaches do for you, and what questions you need to answer yourself before you can proceed to a concrete technical solution.